# Integration over a combination of confluent hypergeometric, power, and exponential functions

Tags: special-functions, approximation, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to work out this integral. If there is no closed form, can you think of any approximations to it?

$$\int_0^T e^{a (T-x)} (T-x)^{1+m+n} x^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+n;2+m+n;a (x-T) \Big) \, dx$$

Thanks for your help!

---

**update:**

I found a couple of relations that helps. That is the closest I got.

At first step, I can use following relation from [1]:

$$_1F_1\Big(1+n;2+m+n;a (x-T)\Big)=e^{a(x-T)} \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;a(T-x)\Big)$$

so I can write the integral as:
$$\int_0^T (T-x)^{1+m+n} x^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;a(T-x) \Big)dx$$
with change of variable $y=T-x$, I can rewrite as:
$$\int_0^T y^{1+m+n} (T-y)^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;ay \Big) \, dy$$
A relation I found on [1] has closed form solution to following integral:
$$\int_0^T y^{1+m+n} (T-y)^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;\color{red}y \Big)dy=T^{2+m+n+k}\frac{\Gamma(2+m+n)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(3+m+n+k)} \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;3+m+n+k;T\Big)$$
since $a>1$ would the answer be an upper bound or a good approximation to my integral? How far this would be?

Thanks!

[1] Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products", 2007 (page 821 and 1023)

Comment: In regards to the update: since the function ${}_1F_1(a,b,x)$ is increasing on $x>0$ when $a,b>0$, the closed form you found in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik will be a **lower bound** for your integral.  [See this plot](http://i.imgur.com/zEudL0a.png), which compares the closed form (in blue) with your integral (in purple) for $1 \leq a \leq 1.5$ with $T=3,k=1,m=1,n=0$.  Note the scale on the vertical axis; it is only a good approximation for $a$ very very close to $1$.

Comment: Thanks so much! You helped me a lot :)

Comment: If your willing to work off line I have developed a technique for this type of problem but have not been able to get the correct answers (yet).

Comment: What is the present question?  Are you looking for bounds or the integral? By a change of variable it seems to me that you already have the absolute integral.

Comment: I am mainly interested in finding the closed form solution of the integral, if possible to write it.

Comment: I have found a paper giving the generic solutions for this type of problem.  http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn2p85_A1b.pdf   If you need more help from the reference I have the books: [5] Slater, L. J., Confluent Hypergeometri c Functions (Cambridge University Press, London, 1960).
[6] Babister, A. W., Transcendental Functions (The Macmillan Co., New York, 1967).   And could provide the referenced equations.

Comment: In the third equation of your update you could do binomial expansion $(T-y)^{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\binom{k}{k}T^{k-n}(-1)^{n}y^{n}$ which leaves you with a power function times your confluent hypergeometric which probably has a solution in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you an approximation for large $a > 0$.  For this I'll assume you mean $\operatorname{Log}(e) = 1$ (an analogous approximation can be found if you mean otherwise).

**The asymptotic formula**

The largest contribution to the integral comes from a neighborhood of $x=0$, and here we have

$$
(T-x)^{1+m+n} \approx T^{1+m+n}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
{}_1F_1\Bigr(1+n,2+m+n,a(x-T)\Bigr) &\approx {}_1F_1(1+n,2+m+n,-aT) \\
&\approx \frac{\Gamma(2+m+n)}{\Gamma(1+m)}\,(aT)^{-1-n},
\end{align}
$$

where the last approximation was given in [my answer to this other question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/349808/5531).

We therefore have, to first order,

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^T e^{a (T-x)} (T-x)^{1+m+n} x^k {}_1F_1\Bigl(1+n;2+m+n;a (x-T)\Bigr) \, dx \\
&\qquad \approx \frac{\Gamma(2+m+n)}{\Gamma(1+m)} \,e^{aT} T^m a^{-1-n} \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} x^k\,dx \\
&\qquad = \frac{\Gamma(1+k)\Gamma(2+m+n)}{\Gamma(1+m)} \,e^{aT} T^m a^{-2-n-k}
\end{align}
$$

with decreasing relative error as $a \to \infty$.  Higher order correction terms can be obtained by using more terms in the binomial series for $(T-x)^{1+m+n}$ and in the asymptotic series for ${}_1F_1$.

**Comparison with the numerics**

If $I(a)$ is your integral and $A(a)$ is the asymptotic formula I derived, then below is the plot of $$e^{-aT}I(a)$$ in blue and $$e^{-aT} A(a)$$ in purple for $a \in [2,6]$ with $T=3$, $k=1$, $m=1$, $n=0$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Antino for your help! Can you please take a look at the update and let me know what you think? That would be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As usual please double check.
You have essentially solved it except for your change of variable:

You have

$_1F_1\Big(1+n;2+m+n;a (x-T)\Big)=e^{a(x-T)} \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;a(T-x)\Big)$
$\int_0^T (T-x)^{1+m+n} x^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;a(T-x) \Big)dx$

Now we apply
$y=a\left(T-x\right)$   , $x=T-\frac{y}{a}=\frac{a\cdot T-y}{a}$, $dx=-\frac{y}{a}$

Adjusting the limits:$0\rightarrow a\cdot T$  , $T\rightarrow0$

Gives

$a^{-(2+m+n+k)}\int^{a\cdot T}_0 y^{1+m+n} (a\cdot T-y)^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;y \Big) \, dy$

I have a different copy of G&R and use section 7.613 (Eq: 1)

We have for $\lambda=2+m+n$  , $c-\lambda-1=k$  or $c=k+3+m+n$

$a^{-(2+m+n+k)}\int^{a\cdot T}_0 y^{1+m+n} (a\cdot T-y)^k \, _1F_1\Big(1+m;2+m+n;y \Big) \, dy$

$=a^{-\left(2+m+n+k\right)}\left(a\cdot T\right)^{k+2+m+n}\frac{\Gamma\left(2+m+n\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(k+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+3+m+n\right)}\,_{1}F_{1}\left(1+m;k+2+m+n;a\cdot T\right)$

$=T^{k+2+m+n}\frac{\Gamma\left(2+m+n\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(k+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+3+m+n\right)}\,_{1}F_{1}\left(1+m;k+3+m+n;a\cdot T\right)$

I don't have a commercial CAS and mine won't simplify the derivative, verifying, without some work; which I will do if you can't.

,