# Bounds on $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{a..\left( a+n-1 \right)}{\left( a+b \right)...\left( a+b+n-1 \right)}\frac{{{z}^{n}}}{n!}}$

Tags: special-functions, approximation, hypergeometric-function

I have a confluent hypergeometric function as $ _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( a,a+b,z \right)$ where $z<0$ and $a,b>0$ and integer.
I am interested to find the bounds on the value it can take or an approximation for it. Since $$0<\frac{a..\left( a+n-1 \right)}{\left( a+b \right)...\left( a+b+n-1 \right)}<1, $$ 
I was thinking that ${{e}^{z}}$ would be an upper bound. Is that right?

I am not sure about lower bound, can this go to $-\infty$?

$$ _{1}{{F}_{1}}\left( a,a+b,z \right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{a..\left( a+n-1 \right)}{\left( a+b \right)...\left( a+b+n-1 \right)}\frac{{{z}^{n}}}{n!}}\le {{e}^{z}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: What are the restrictions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: both are greater than zero

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the asymptotic formula,

$$
{}_1F_1(a,a+b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(b)} (-z)^{-a} + O(z^{-a-1})
$$

as $\operatorname{Re} z \to -\infty$ (see, e.g., [1]).

Note, in particular, that it is **not** true that ${}_1F_1(a,a+b,x) \leq e^x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ large and negative.

[1] Bateman Manuscript Project, *Higher Transcendental Functions*.  Vol. 1, p. 248,255,278. [[pdf](http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf)]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I checked the reference, very useful. If I am correct, you are referring to the relation on page 76 of the pdf. I noticed there $z^{-a}$ instead of $-z^{-a}$. Am I right? If that is the case, can we still say that $e^z$ can still be used as an upper bound.
Also in the reference it uses $\lambda_1$ as coefficient. How did you know that it will be $\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(b)}$.

Comment: I should add that a,b are integers. Reference says that in that case, we need to multiply $z^{-a}$ by $log(z)$.Thanks

Comment: @Eln, no, I'm using the second formula in equation (3) on page 278 (page number in the top left corner). It is the 302nd page of the PDF.  The capital $\Phi$ function there is the function ${}_1F_1$, as you can check from the integral representation on page 255.

Comment: @Eln, Also, I just want to reiterate that $e^z$ is certainly not an upper bound as $z \to -\infty$.  For $z$ large and negative enough the opposite will be true, that ${}_1F_1 \geq e^z$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Are those $x$s on the last line meant to be $z$s?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, thanks for pointing that out.  I was trying to differentiate the complex case $z \in \mathbb{C}$ from the real case $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (where we can write inequalities) and ended up confusing the two.

Answer (score 1):

The following fact helps you to find an upper bound, since $a,b>0$, then we have

$$ \frac{(a)_n}{(a+b)_n} \leq 1,\quad \forall n\geq 0, $$

where $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol $ (a)_n = \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(a)} $. The above inequality can be proved easily by using the fact

$$ (a + b)_{n} = \sum_{{j=0}}^n {n \choose j} (a)_{n-j}(b)_{j}. $$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am trying to prove it but not sure. Can you please elaborate more how can I prove that $e^z$ holds as an upper bound. Thanks again!